# Downloading and running a JAR from memory in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, jar, download

I have a C# application, where I need to download and run a JAR file, without it being saved to disk. Is this possible in C#? I can download files via WebClient just fine to disk (which is what I'm doing as of posting) & launch it via a batch script which is saved then deleted, but I want to take it a step further by not having anything touch the drive.

Thanks.

Comment: You know that JAR means Java, right?

Comment: it is complicated but in theory possible although absolutely not recommended... please show some source code... what have you tried ? what is not working ?

Comment: Yes, I do realize this is Java, which is why I'm asking. I've done this in Java just fine. I don't have any code for it at the moment since I have no idea where to start. I edited the OP stating what I can do so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write a special Java class loader that loads classes via interprocess communication (IPC) from the .NET process instead of from a file. In addition, you'll need a small launcher JAR that first installs the class loader and then executes the JAR retrieved via IPC. And you'll need to implement the server part of the IPC communication in your .NET application.

But is it worth it? What would be the benefit of such a complex piece of software?

Comment: Seems like a lot of trouble to go through, I think I'll keep to just saving to disk then. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

A JAR file needs to executed by javaw.exe, the JVM.  Another process doesn't have the power to reach into your virtual memory space and read the file data.  Not unless *both* processes co-operate and use a shared memory section.  You get no such co-operation from javaw.exe, it requires a file.

This is a non-issue in Windows since javaw.exe will actually read the file from memory.  When you write the file in your program, you actually write to the file system cache.  Which buffers file data in RAM, delay-writing it to the disk.  As long as the file isn't to big (gigabyte or more) and you don't wait too long to start java (minutes) and the machine has enough RAM (gigabyte or two) then javaw.exe reads the file from the file system cache.  RAM, not disk.  Exact same idea as a RAM-disk of old.